# How to resolve possibly conflicting urls in webpage rendering

Tags: python, django, templates, rendering, url-pattern

When I try to load a page, I get another page instead...
I try to load a page called wikiPage as shown in my urls description that follows, but I get another url patterns linking to a view called newPageb instead, though the two urls have same parameters and the one that is first in order gets called, But how do I make them distinct where I can call them irrespective of order.

Here is my urls.py...

```
app_name= "encyclopedia"
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("randomPage", views.randomPage, name="randomPage"),
    path("<str:pagetitle>", views.newPageb, name="newPageb"),
    path("<str:pagetitle>", views.wikiPage, name="wikiPage"),
    path("<str:z>", views.wikiPage, name="wikiPage"),
    path("newPage", views.newPage, name="newPage"),
    path("<str:pageSearch>", views.search, name="search"),
    path("", views.search, name="search")
```

```
Here are the conflicting views..
def newPageb(request, pagetitle)
...
...
def wikiPage(request, pagetitle):
...
...
```

and here is the template where the pagetitle parameter was declared

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}
"

{% block title %}
    Encyclopedia
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1> {{title}} </h1>
    <ul>
        {% for pagetitle in entries %}
        <li>
           <a href="{% url 'encyclopedia:wikiPage' pagetitle=pagetitle%}"> {{ pagetitle }} </a>
        </li>
          {{entrie|safe}}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The code doesn't work already how did you get an error? You have two `name="wikiPage"` in urlpatterns

Answer (score 0):

because you have two routes that match, because of which django chooses the first suitable template for the url address and does not look at the following addresses.

```
path("<str:pagetitle>", views.newPageb, name="newPageb"),    
path("<str:pagetitle>", views.wikiPage, name="wikiPage")
```

to solve this problem you need to change one of the addresses. example

```
path("new-page/<str:pagetitle>", views.newPageb, name="newPageb"),    
path("<str:pagetitle>", views.wikiPage, name="wikiPage")
```

Comment: COOL!!! It worked!  Thanks SerhiiL. You've contributed immensely to save me weeks of head aches. God bless u